# How to display Chrome window only on active screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, google-chrome, gnome-shell, monitor, ubuntu-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2. I want to be able to do like I could back when I used Windows where you have a dock on each screen but all screens only show the programs / active windows that are on their respective screens.

I have searched and searched and have not found the answer to this. Can someone please tell me how to do this? It is the only last thing I have to figure out since my switch to Ubuntu full time.

Comment: @pomsky 18.04.2

Comment: @pomsky Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As pomsky linked to as a duplicate the answer was running the below command in the terminal and it started working right away no need for reloading anything.

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock isolate-monitors true`